# Adding a column to multiple excel spreadsheets, with column entries being the name of the excel filename. Then combining sheets into one spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I need to merge multiple spreadsheets into not only one workbook, but also into one combined spreadsheet. Each file has over 1000 rows and there are three directories with about 40-50 such files. These can be combined separately as they represent personnel records across three years.

I have a VBA Macro that successfully places the sheets into one workbook. I also have a Macro for combining these sheets into one appended spreadsheet. However, I need to take out the header row for each successive file data addition after the first row of the combined file.

Further, I need to either use a Macro to create a column in each file with each row being filled with the file name (such that once combined with the other files it is clear which source each data point is coming from) or find a Macro that does this while combining the sheets. If it's the former using a Macro that does this for every file, prior to my using the single spreadsheet combination Macro, then all I need is an update to my final Macro that only puts a header row for the first row. Here is an example of the data:

[image]

I need the final file to have the column in A, the newly created column, have the file name of each file source from which the row came. See an example below of what I'd like the combined result to look like:

[image]

Here is the Macro I am using for combining the multiple tabs/spreadsheets into one spreadsheet:

```
Sub Merge_Sheets()
    'Insert a new worksheet
    Sheets.Add

    'Rename the new worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "YearlyCompilation"

    'Loop through worksheets and copy the to your new worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Activate

        'Don't copy the merged sheet again
        If ws.Name <> "YearlyCompilation" Then
            ws.UsedRange.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("YearlyCompilation").Activate

            'Select the last filled cell
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").Select
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select

            'For the first worksheet you don't need to go down one cell
            If ActiveCell.Address <> "$A$1" Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If

            'Instead of just paste, you can also paste as link, as values etc.
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Since it looks like you're moving all of the worksheets into a single workbook first, how do you plan to store the filename? Is using the worksheet name an option?

Comment: Yes, my first macro has code that when importing the separate spreadsheets it makes the tab/sheet they import into be named the name of the original file. If there is a macro you suggest that can merge these files into one sheet without first creating a combined workbook, please let me know. For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy After:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                    wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count).Name = Left(wksCurSheet.Name & wbkSrcBook.Name, 31)

Comment: That's less easy, I'm writing something quickly that will do what your question asked efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe long winded, and may have missed the mark, but the macro below will combine the values of multiple worksheets that share dimensions and a header row into a new worksheet with an additional column for the filename and only one header row.

It will not preserve source formatting or formulas, and it uses arrays to build the new worksheet in VBA-space for speed reasons. I've also included an error check if the input sheets have a different number of columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Merge_Sheets()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim varInput() As Variant
    Dim varOutput() As Variant
    Dim colData As Collection
    Dim colWsName As Collection
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lColumns As Long
    Dim lOutputRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim l As Long

    OptimizationON

    Set colData = New Collection
    Set colWsName = New Collection

    'Loads source data into Array, then loads array into a collection
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        varInput() = ws.UsedRange.Value2
        colData.Add varInput()
        colWsName.Add ws.name

    Next ws

    lRows = 0
    lColumns = 0

    'Determines how many rows and columns the final output array will need
    For i = 1 To colData.Count
        lRows = lRows + UBound(colData(i))

        If i = 1 Then
            lColumns = UBound(colData(i), 2)

        Else
            If lColumns <> UBound(colData(i), 2) Then
                MsgBox "Input worksheets have a different number of columns!", vbCritical, "ERROR!"
                OptimizationOFF
                Exit Sub

            End If

        End If

    Next i

    lColumns = lColumns + 1
    lRows = lRows - i + 2

    'Initializes the output array
    ReDim varOutput(1 To lRows, 1 To lColumns)

    'Loads the data into the output array
    lOutputRow = 1
    l = 0

    For i = 1 To colData.Count
        If i > 1 Then l = 1

        For j = 1 To UBound(colData(i)) - l
            For k = 1 To UBound(colData(i), 2) + 1
                If k = 1 Then
                    If lOutputRow = 1 Then
                        varOutput(lOutputRow, k) = "Filename"

                    Else
                        varOutput(lOutputRow, k) = colWsName(i)

                    End If

                Else
                    varOutput(lOutputRow, k) = colData(i)(j + l, k - 1)

                End If
            Next k

            lOutputRow = lOutputRow + 1

        Next j

    Next i

    'Creates a new worksheet and loads the data into it
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    ws.name = "YearlyCompilation"

    ArrayToWorksheet varOutput(), ws

ErrorHandler:
    OptimizationOFF

End Sub

Private Sub ArrayToWorksheet(ByVal varArray As Variant, ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    'Loads an array into a worksheet
    Dim range As range

    Set range = ws.range("A1")

    Debug.Assert range.Address = "$A$1"

    Set range = range.Resize(UBound(varArray, 1), UBound(varArray, 2))

    range.Value2 = varArray

End Sub

Private Sub OptimizationON()
    'Disables certain features to speed up calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .PrintCommunication = False

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub OptimizationOFF()
    'Re-enables disabled features
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .PrintCommunication = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much! One thing I realized is that some of the files DO have a different amount of columns. About halfway through 2017 these weekly personnel files are missing a few fields such as PTO (Paid Time Off). Hence the error message is coming up as intended. Do you know a way to combine these separately or do I need to create batches of files with the same amount of columns and fields? In the latter I would then need to separate 2017 into batches with the same field numbers.

Comment: @PolicyGuy The macro isn't checking the column headers, so if there are missing columns in the middle then the data will be misaligned. I'd really recommend having all of your data in the same general 'shape' before combining it. Working around that would make the code much more complex.

Comment: @PolicyGuy Please upvote and accept the answer when you have a moment if/when it fits your needs :)

Comment: Right, makes sense. The macro does work for those spreadsheets with the same number of columns. Thanks again friend! I am new to this relatively. How do I accept the answer? It says I can't upvote visibly until I have 15 reputation.

Comment: @PolicyGuy There should be a little check mark underneath the voting buttons